# Querying over many to many field

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, django-orm

I have following models setup in my Django application

```
 class School(models.Model):
   name  = models.TextField()

 class Courses(models.Model):
   name  = models.TextField()
   schools = ManyToManyField(School)
```

Now, I want to find out all schools which offer a particular course. For example, find all schools which offer biology and chemistry. What query can I use?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [lookup that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) in the manual:

```
class Courses(models.Model):
   name  = models.TextField()
   schools = ManyToManyField(School, related_name='courses_set')

School.objects.filter(courses_set__name__in=('biology', 'chemistry'))
```

Comment: I am getting error 'cannot resolve keyword courses_set' into field

Comment: Try settings the `related_name`.